# Entity Framework The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

On updating database in Entity Framework , Code first Migration, I am getting this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.MedicalGroups_MedicalGroupId". The conflict occurred in database "hrbc", table "dbo.MedicalGroups", column 'Id'.

This is my class:

```
public partial class Client
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? MedicalGroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MedicalGroupId")]
    public virtual MedicalGroups MedicalGroup { get { return _MedicalGroup; } set { _MedicalGroup = value; } }
}
```

Here is my 2nd class:

```
public partial class MedicalGroups
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my migration which I am trying to apply:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Clients", "MedicalGroupId", "dbo.MedicalGroups", "Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Clients", "MedicalGroupId");
}
```

Comment: I think you need to delete FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.MedicalGroups_MedicalGroupId

Comment: did you change model before this step, what's up the situtation in Down() case ? If you do something wrong before you should delete ex-index from database as mention @brykneval

Comment: @brykneval there is no problem regarding the name because i do change the name of foreign key constraint but no help!!!

Comment: @AOZ Yes i have added the medical group table in DB. Now i want to make an association between client and medical group. And there is no code in down() method

Comment: @AOZ Suppose if i did something wrong than how could i know?

Comment: ok what is the meaning of getter and setter public virtual MedicalGroups MedicalGroup { get { return _MedicalGroup; } set { _MedicalGroup = value; } } and where is the _MedicalGroup, and why do you need custom getter and setter. Normallay there should not be a problem..

Comment: @AOZ there is no problem here because i also tried the default setter and getter but still it coudn't solve my prblem

Comment: MedicalGroupId is existing field right? And then you want to relate to table after. Please check client table records which contains MedicalGroupId field is not null, then update all Clients to change MedicakGroupId field null

Comment: Yes MedicalGroupId is existing field and i want to relate table after but my MedicalGroupId is nullable. and how can i update all clients to change MedicakGroupIdfield null???

Comment: @AOZ do you want me to change the property name of MedicalGroupId in client.cs to MedicakGroupId???

Comment: no its a mistake, you can update Client table like "Update Client set MedicalGroupId = NULL"

Comment: @AOZ dont you think i will lose the record in that way???

Comment: yes i thougt that possibility, but if data is important for you can warn me, if you did not update the table, you can check all not existed MedicalGroupId in MedicalGroups table and then you must insert  the Ids to MedicalGroups table

Comment: yes data is too important... and i didnt get your last point about "MedicalGroup table"???

Comment: He's saying that if there is a MedicalGroupId foreign key in the Clients table then make sure there is a matching ID primary key in the MedicalGroups table.  If not then add that ID to the MedicalGroups table.

Comment: See also [The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](//stackoverflow.com/q/21839309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution of my Problem. Problem is "data" which i have in my clients table. Because my client table have medicalgroupid values which are not actually exist that's why it is giving me error on foreign key constraint.

```
Update Client set MedicalGroupId = NULL
```

Comment: In that case then please mark Cory or my answer as the solution as that's what we were advising to check.

Answer (score 144):

Check that there is not existing data in the database that is conflicting with the FK constraint causing the creation to fail.

Comment: but MedicalGroupId is not mandatory.. There should not be problem with the existing data

Comment: @turnkey yes there is already data in my client table but i cannot delete it.

Comment: @AOZ So do have any solution?

Comment: i wrote my last comment to your post >> MedicalGroupId is existing field right? And then you want to relate to table after. Please check client table records which contains MedicalGroupId field is not null, then update all Clients to change MedicakGroupId field null

Comment: Check that any existing keys are pointing to valid MedicalGroups.Id.

Comment: It is not about deleting data but about fixing them. If there is `Client` with reference to non existing `MedicalGroup`, you will never be able to add the FK.

Comment: I had the same issue, query the data as update script for the column, set column to null for all values. After that run migration, which successful and  run the update script to put data back.

Comment: In my case i had set the foreign key property as int instead of int? so EF was adding a default value of 0 which was pointing to no entry in the foreign table.

Comment: I thought it was something wrong related with my classes definitions. Oh my, thanks!

Answer (score 41):

I think @Cory was getting you close to the correct solution, you just did not take the time to investigate.

In add-migration  code, the migration probably generated

```
public override void Up()
{
AddColumn("dbo.ClientContacts", "FamilialRelationshipId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
CreateIndex("dbo.ClientContacts", "FamilialRelationshipId");
AddForeignKey("dbo.ClientContacts", "FamilialRelationshipId", "dbo.FamilialRelationships",        "FamilialRelationshipId");
}
```

Notice nullable:false; If your Model had an Id of int instead of int? (nullable int) the migration code will set nullable to false.
Your model shows you are using a non-nullable int which defaults to 0, and you probably don't have a foreign key item with a value of 0.

Now, you will have to either create a default value, that exists in the foreign key table,
or Create the Constraint with no check if you are using SQL Server to create the constraint.  Remember this though: If you decorate your property with a [DefaultValue(0)] attribute, it won't change the existing data, like a SQL Column Add would, if a default value was specified.

I recommend you change your Model Class to allow a nullable int. 
Then, in your seed method, create a simple method against dbcontext to update the new column with a default value, because the [DefaultValue] attribute in data annotations will   not modify your data.

Add-Migration / Update-Database to create the column and constraint.
Next, modify your model if you desire to allow for a non-nullable int, and presuming you changed all rows to some valid value for the foreign key, Add-Migration / Update-database again.
This gives you an unbroken chain in your model migration.  Will come in handy later when you publish to a live site, because the flow of your data model changes will be intact.

- Hope this helps.

Comment: We ran into a problem with the two-step solution here.  If multiple migrations have to be applied at once, you end up with the following sequence: create the nullable field, make it non-nullable, then run the seed.  There's no place to actually put data into the FK field, and everything explodes again.  The only two solutions I've found around this are either to delete the data from the table that links to the FK, or make the field nullable and keep it that way.

Comment: @AriRoth +1 but surely there's another way, how common must this be?!

Answer (score 21):

This error is telling you that you are violating the foreign key constraint.  To resolve you have a few solutions

1. **Fix your data** - Somewhere there are records in the `Clients` table that have a *MedicalGroupId* that does not exist in the in the
   `MedicalGroups` table.  Write a query to find out what IDs do not
   exist in the `MedicalGroups` table and manually fix the data
   yourself.
2. **Remove the foreign key constraint** - Obviously if you remove the foreign key constraint you will no longer be bothered by this message.  Unfortunately the database will no longer enforce this relationship and might make this problem worse in the future.
3. **Create constraint using `WITH NOCHECK`** - You can create your foreign key constraint using the `WITH NOCHECK` option.  This option tells SQL Server to not apply this constraint to existing data.  SQL Server WILL check this constraint in any future INSERTS/UPDATES/DELETES.

Answer (score 12):

this problem appear because your table is not empty.
so you shoud add the new field without attaching it like foreign key.
`public int? MedicalGroupId { get; set; }`.And execute `update-database` command in package manage console. 
Then fill the field in this table(client) with the right data (value exists in MedicalGroupsId).
Insert the line to create the foreign key

```
[ForeignKey("MedicalGroupId")]
public virtual MedicalGroups MedicalGroup { get { return _MedicalGroup; } set { _MedicalGroup = value; } }
```

in the end execute the `update-database` command. It will be ok.

Answer (score 11):

For others that may land here, there could be a really simple fix if you're using Code-First Entity Framework and just trying to add a new required column to a table with existing data.

Note: Before you do this, just know that you will need to add a valid value to this new column for all existing rows. Think about what value you will add to the existing rows before proceeding. You may want to provide a value that indicates "Invalid" or "Unknown" to the required lookup table.

In your model, set the column to nullable by adding the ? after the int. Save and compile the model. Run Update-Database.

Example:

```html
[ForeignKey("Title")]
public int? TitleId { get; set; }
```

In the db, update the table by replacing the NULL values with a valid lookup value. In my case, I added "Unknown" to my Title lookup table and then bulk edited all rows to reference that lookup Id.

Back in your model, remove the '?' so the column is no longer nullable. Save and compile the model and then run Update-Database

You should now be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well with defaultValue set, gave:

"The object is dependent on column ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because one or more objects access this column".

Ended up move the AddForeignKey/DropForeignKey to a new migration and ran them in separate update-database commands (dont excecute both migrations in one command then it failed for me.)

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.DecisionAccesses",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.DecisionPersonStatus",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.DecisionForm_DecisionFields", "DecisionAccessId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: (int)DecisionAccess.Creator));
        AddColumn("dbo.DecisionMatterPersons", "DecisionPersonStatusId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: (int)DecisionAccess.Creator));
        CreateIndex("dbo.DecisionForm_DecisionFields", "DecisionAccessId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.DecisionMatterPersons", "DecisionPersonStatusId");
        //I moved outcommented to next migration and ran the migrations in separate steps to avoid: (The object is dependent on column ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because one or more objects access this column)
        //AddForeignKey("dbo.DecisionForm_DecisionFields", "DecisionAccessId", "dbo.DecisionAccesses", "Id", cascadeDelete: true); 
        //AddForeignKey("dbo.DecisionMatterPersons", "DecisionPersonStatusId", "dbo.DecisionPersonStatus", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }


    public override void Down()
    {
        //Moved to next migration
        //DropForeignKey("dbo.DecisionMatterPersons", "DecisionPersonStatusId", "dbo.DecisionPersonStatus");
        //DropForeignKey("dbo.DecisionForm_DecisionFields", "DecisionAccessId", "dbo.DecisionAccesses");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen if you have orphan records in the child table. Clean up the database should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your migrations are in correct order i.e. table associated with Foreign key will get created before the reference. Follow the following steps:

1. Backup current database from SQL management studio (If required)
2. Delete database from SQL management studio
3. Type 'Update-Database'in Visual Studio 'Package Manager Console'

Answer (score 0):

Run the **Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges** command in Package Manager Console. This creates an empty migration with the current model as a snapshot.

Run the **Update-Database** command in Package Manager Console. This will apply the InitialCreate migration to the database. Since the actual migration doesn’t contain any changes, it will simply add a row to the __MigrationsHistory table indicating that this migration has already been applied.

You can get more detail here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I also received this message. The problem was that the test data in the db was incorrect.
I didn't have validation on when I was testing and hence i had null values for IDs for fields that do not allow nulls. Once I fixed the data, the update-database command ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Had that issue but fortunately I was just building my tables. I only had a couple sample items in each table. Deleted all the rows in both tables then it worked. I'm a noob so take it for what it's worth

Answer (score 0):

You could also use data seeding via

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalGroups>()
.HasData(new MedicalGroups { ... }, new MedicalGroups { ... })
```

in your DbContexts class OnModelCreating method.

That way you can insert all the MedicalData rows whos Id is missing from the referencing table. At least in my case the data got seeded bofere it was needed and update-database worked properly.