# How to add a new Foreign Key from a new table to existing records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

Using C# MVC and Entity Framework v6.2.0

I have an existing Model, `Caller`

```
public class Caller
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a new Model, `LanguageChoice`

```
public class LanguageChoice
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add this new `LanguageChoice` to `Caller`

```
public class Caller
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public Guid LanguageChoice_Id { get; set; } // <----

    [ForeignKey("LanguageChoice_Id")]
    public LanguageChoice LanguageChoice { get; set; } // <----
}
```

I'm doing it this way because it will be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in my ViewModel.

In my database, I have existing `Caller` records:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║         Id          ║ FirstName ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ caller_guid_value_1 ║ Ryan      ║
║ caller_guid_value_2 ║ John      ║
╚═════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

And when I add the `LanguageChoice`, the expected outcome would be this:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║         Id          ║ FirstName ║      LanguageChoice_Id      ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ caller_guid_value_1 ║ Ryan      ║ languageChoice_guid_value_1 ║
║ caller_guid_value_2 ║ John      ║ languageChoice_guid_value_1 ║
╚═════════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

This is my Migration:

```
public partial class AddCallerLanguageChoice : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LanguageChoices",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", "dbo.LanguageChoices", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", "dbo.LanguageChoices");
        DropIndex("dbo.Callers", new[] { "LanguageChoice_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id");
        DropTable("dbo.LanguageChoices");
    }
}
```

Which get's me the error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Callers_dbo.LanguageChoices_LanguageChoice_Id". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-My Web App-20171030040324", table "dbo.LanguageChoices", column 'Id'.

**Is there anyway to do this, or should I just move forward allowing `LanguageChoice_Id` to be nullable?**

---

Similar question from 4 years ago: [Entity Framework The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871349/entity-framework-the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-const)

- 4 years old, maybe something has changed since then
- They are using `int` values for Ids, I'm using `Guid`, so I can't guess/assume the Id value ahead of time
- I want to avoid creating one migration where `LanguageChoice_Id` is nullable, followed by a seed method that updates records, then followed by another migration that makes `LanguageChoice_Id` not-nullable as that would break when pushing both migrations to Azure since the seed method would run last. (See Ari Roth's comment to RicklsWright's answer)

---

Update:

Following [@henoc salinas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7782179/henoc-salinas)' updated answer I came to this single migration file that works.

Henoc's answer is the accepted answer, this is just to show what I ultimately ended up with, differences being that I inserted the table values here and updated the null values of `Caller` using a non-temp value:

```
        public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LanguageChoices",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        Sql(String.Format("INSERT INTO LanguageChoices VALUES ('{0}','{1}')", Guid.NewGuid(), "English"));
        Sql(String.Format("INSERT INTO LanguageChoices VALUES ('{0}','{1}')", Guid.NewGuid(), "Other"));
        Sql(String.Format("INSERT INTO LanguageChoices VALUES ('{0}','{1}')", Guid.NewGuid(), "Spanish"));

        AddColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: true));

        Sql("UPDATE Callers Set LanguageChoice_Id = (SELECT Id FROM LanguageChoices WHERE Name = \'English\') WHERE LanguageChoice_Id IS NULL");

        AlterColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));

        CreateIndex("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", "dbo.LanguageChoices", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", "dbo.LanguageChoices");
        DropIndex("dbo.Callers", new[] { "LanguageChoice_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id");
        DropTable("dbo.LanguageChoices");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing has changed so far (unfortunately).

Comment: @IvanStoev well that's a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this conflict is generated because the new table LanguageChoices doesn't have elements when it's created, so, the foreign key does not find a valid value because it is not nullable, you can try change:

```
 public Guid LanguageChoice_Id { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
  public Guid? LanguageChoice_Id { get; set; }
```

then generate again the migration, with this you can see the line:

```
 AddColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
```

is changed to this:

```
 AddColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", c => c.Guid());
```

Now, you can update the database, and for change the column to not null, add valid values and change again the line, then generate a new migration:

```
public Guid? LanguageChoice_Id { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public Guid LanguageChoice_Id { get; set; }
```

**after your commentaries**

insert a sql code on marks:

```
public partial class AddCallerLanguageChoice : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LanguageChoices",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        string TempKey = Guid.NewGuid ( ).ToString();
        this.Sql ( String.Format ( "Insert into dbo.LanguageChoices values ({0},{1})", TempKey, "Initial" ) );

        AddColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));

        Sql ( String.Format ( "Update dbo.Callers set LanguageChoice_Id='{0}' where LanguageChoice_Id is null", TempKey ) );

        CreateIndex("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", "dbo.LanguageChoices", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id", "dbo.LanguageChoices");
        DropIndex("dbo.Callers", new[] { "LanguageChoice_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Callers", "LanguageChoice_Id");
        DropTable("dbo.LanguageChoices");
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs into the problem I mentioned at the bottom of my post. I were to push both migrations at once to a different server (and I will be) I would get an error as I wouldn't be able to change the null values before EF tries to update them to a non-nullable field.

Comment: Have you tried to insert a sql code to assign values to the new column after creating the column in the migration and the new table?

Comment: You can include the SQL to update the fields directly in `Up` method of an intermediate migration between the schema change migrations that contains nothing but the update statements: `Sql("UPDATE .....");`

Comment: Using your suggestion, @BradleyUffner, I have this statement in it's own Migration: `string sqlStatement = "UPDATE Callers SET LanguageChoice_Id = \'" + languageChoice.Id + "\' WHERE LanguageChoice_Id IS NULL"; Sql(sqlStatement);` followed by a migration that makes `LanguageChoice_Id` not nullable, which works when doing one migration at a time but not all at once. I have to use `ApplicationDbContext` to get the `Id` value, so in the middle of the migration it errors saying ApplicationDbContext has changed.

Comment: @RyanTaite Can you update the question to show the entire `Up` method you are using for the migration with the update statement?  You won't be able to use the `DbContext` within that migration, since it doesn't match the schema of the DB at that point in time, it will have to be done using pure SQL.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question just now to show it. I'll try to write the full SQL statement instead of using `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: i edited my answere, plase see again after the comments